# To check absolute convergence of series

Tags: sequences-and-series

[image]

Attempt - i used ratio test for absolute version and it is convergent absolutely ,but i am not sure ?

Comment: I would suggest to show us your solution so we can check it or tell you where is a mistake.

Comment: Can you show how you applied the ratio test? It will make it easier to answer your question.

Comment: @UmbertoP. i got 4/e^{2} after doing ratio test .Am i wrong ?

Comment: It seems reasonable. Why are you unsure?

Comment: @UmbertoP. have u checked it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** Recall that, as $n \to \infty$, applying [Stirling's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) to $(2n)!$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{(2n)!}{n^{2n} }
& \sim \sqrt{2\pi n}\:\left(\! \frac{4}{e^2}\!\right)^n
\end{align}
$$ and since$$
0<\frac{4}{e^2}<1
$$ then your **initial series is absolutely convergent**.

Comment: so i need not to worry about conditionally convergent case

Comment: @godonichia No, since the series is absolutely convergent.